# Use mput to transfer a directory using ftp?

Tags: command-line, ftp

Is there anyway to convince mput to send all sub directories of the current directory to the server. I'm trying to write a script to automatically update a website when it is run. So far ive been trying

```
 mput *
```

but that only sends the files in the current directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it. The windows ftp client does not support a recursive put function. However, using ncftp: 
http://www.ncftp.com/
im able to do a recursive put with `mput -r *`

Answer (score 3):

A simple tutorial for other Windows newbies like me who wind up here:

The easiest way to upload an entire folder (with all subfolders and files in them) is:

1. Download [NcFTP Client](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) (it's free, but you can donate) [from this link](http://www.ncftp.com/download/).
2. Choose **NcFTP Client 3.2.5 for Microsoft Windows** from the list.
3. Install it.
4. When done, a small CMD window with a cherries icon will pop-up. You don't need it.
5. Just open a standard CMD window and type:

   ```
   ncftpput -u *yourUserNameHere* -p *yourUserPasswordHere* -R *www.yourWebsite.com* /
                    _C:\yourFolderDirectoryHere\\*_
   ```

   (as one line).

Note that:

- `-R`  is a flag for "recursive"; it makes the command copy all subfolders recursively
- `/` (slash) is your website's root directory
- `C:\yourFolderDirectoryHere\*` selects everything inside *`C:\yourFolderDirectoryHere`*